# How to solve this limits question?

Tags: calculus, limits

Question:-

> Let $$f(x) = \left(\frac{k \cos(x)}{\pi - 2x}\right)$$ Where $$x\ne \frac{\pi}{2}$$
>   And $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 3$$
>   if $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}f(x) =  f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
>   Then find the value of $k$

My attempt :-

> $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{k \cos(x)}{\pi - 2x}\right)$$
>   Now as $x \to {\pi\over2}$, $\cos x \to \cos{\pi\over2}$ and $(\pi - 2x) \to 0$
>
> $\therefore$ we can write $(\pi - 2x) \to \cos{\pi\over2}$ because $\cos{\pi\over2} = 0$
>   $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{k \cos(x)}{\pi - 2x}\right)$$ 
>   $$= \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{k \cos(x)}{\cos x}\right)$$
>   $$= \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}k = k$$
>   $$ \therefore k = 3$$

But the right answer is $6$ and if i write $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{k \cos(x)}{\pi - 2x}\right)$$ as $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{{k\over2} \cos(x)}{{\pi\over2} - x}\right)$$ and follow rest of my logic i will get $6$ as the answer.

I don't think manipulating it like this is correct way of doing this question.

Can any one please explain me how to do this question correctly ?

Please can anybody show me a answer without using special cases or theorems.

Comment: May be helpful:$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos x - 0}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos' \frac{\pi}{2}$$ by definition.

Comment: @ClementC. What is $cos' {\pi\over2}$ ?

Comment: $f'(a)$ is the derivative of $f$ at point $a$. So it is the derivative of $\cos$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e. $-\sin \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @ClementC. as i guessed but i can't use it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{k\cos x}{\pi-2x}
$$
Use the substitution $x=\pi/2-t$, so $t=\pi/2-x$ and $\pi-2x=2t$; then the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{k\cos(\pi/2-t)}{2t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{k}{2}\frac{\sin t}{t}=\frac{k}{2}
$$
If you are given that the limit is $3$, then $k=6$.

Comment: I can't use $\sin x \over x$

Comment: @ritwiksinha Then what **can** you use? Including this in your question would make a *lot* of sense.

Comment: @ritwiksinha So, *what* are you allowed to use? Unfortunately your work is completely wrong.

Comment: @egreg i can only use bare basics of limits, no other theorems or special cases.

Comment: @ClementC. i will edit the question.

Comment: @ritwiksinha Sorry, but this is impossible; the limit you're given is *equivalent* to computing $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$ which is *not* doable with “basic of limits”. You at least need the squeeze theorem or to prove it.

Comment: @egreg ok but with **ONLY** squeeze theorem, how will do it ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha You prove that, for $x\ne0$, $\cos x\le \frac{\sin x}{x}\le\frac{1}{\cos x}$. Geometric proofs of this are available everywhere.

Comment: @egreg i know that proof but if i am anyway going to prove this then i should just use $\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin x\over x}$. Anyway thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out L'Hospital's rule here.

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{k * \cos(x)}{\pi - 2*x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{{d\over dx}(k * \cos(x))}{{d\over dx}(\pi - 2*x)}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{-k * \sin(x)}{- 2}\right)$$

$$={k\over 2}=3(given)$$

$$\therefore k=6$$

Comment: That is the problem. I can't do this type of magic to solve it, i need to do it by bare basics of limits.

Comment: Also, L'Hopital here is circular (it works, but it's circular), since the very limit is up to a factor $-2$ the definition of the derivative of $\cos$ already.

Answer (score 0):

Since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{k\cos x}{\pi-2x} &=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{k\cos (x-\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi-2x}\\
&=-\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{k\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi-2x}\\
&=\frac{k}{2},
\end{align*}
therefore $k=6$.